# HttpPostedFile.SaveAs access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, file-permissions

I'm trying to save a file that I upload from my page but I'm getting an access denied error:

```
public void SaveFile(Item item, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var dir = string.Format(@"{0}\NSN\{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentLocation"].ToString(), item.Id.ToString());

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

        Array.ForEach(Directory.GetFiles(dir), File.Delete);

        file.SaveAs(dir);
    }
```

I'm running this site from the local host from visual studio so no app pool is involved. I've given the Network Service (and Everyone as a test) full control of the folder and it's subfolders. Strange thing is it creates the folder if it needs to and also deletes any files in an existing folder. Only when I call the SaveAs function do I get the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call `file.SaveAs` with path to directory instead of path to file

Comment: What a numpty. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Here, give this a try:

```
string saveAsPath = Path.Combine(dir, file);
file.SaveAs(saveAsPath);
```

Replace `file.SaveAs(dir)` with the above.